# Survival function as output label for supervised dimensionality reduction

Tags: survival, dimensionality-reduction, supervised-learning

I would like to do supervised dimensionality reduction with [UMAP](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/supervised.html?highlight=supervised) for survival analysis.

As both the time to event as well as the event itself are of interest for survival analysis, I calculated the survival function through the Kaplan-Meier estimator. I then use the function's value at survival time $t$ of each sample as the output labels.

Is it safe to do this? Or do I have to additionally take into consideration censored data?

Answer (score 1):

A properly generated Kaplan-Meier curve inherently takes censoring into account. So if you provided the Kaplan-Meier algorithm with the necessary indications of event versus censoring for each observation time, you should be all set with respect to censoring. The question is whether the survival values at a specified time $t$ will be sufficiently distinct among clusters to serve reliably as "output labels."

A similar approach seems to have been implemented by [Mandel et al](https://bmccancer.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12885-020-06756-x) and applied to gene expression and survival data from The Cancer Genome Atlas. A quick read suggests that they used median survival, instead of survival fraction at a specified time, to describe the gene-expression clusters.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my question regarding censoring! If I understood the approach from Mandel et al. correctly, they are using median survival after clustering to assess the plausibility of the clusters created by t-SNE. As I don't have any predefined clusters when doing dimensionality reduction in my approach, I would assume it's not possible for me to use median survival as target/output label. Or do you have an idea how this could be applied here?

Comment: @hlzl if your question is about how to use survival outcomes to supervise learning with respect to clustering things like gene-expression values, please edit your question and its title to make that clear. That's a different situation from having predefined clusters that you then label with their associated survival characteristics, which is the way that the current version of this question reads. The more details you can provide in the question about your situation, the more likely you are to get a helpful answer.